# App crashes at setImageResource()

Tags: java, android

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
```

Here's my code:

```
NewsFeed.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        //Your code to run in GUI thread here 
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
    }
});
```

This code is running in a `doInBackground()` method. This is my `ImageView` in XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

NewsFeed.java

```
public class NewsFeed extends ListActivity {
    MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    // json url

    // json tags
    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    private static final String TAG_CREATETIME = "created_time";
    protected static final String JSONObject = null;

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    TimerTask timerTask;
    Handler handler;
    Timer ourtimer;
    String url, gotToken, static_token, imgUrl, nextUrl = "none",
            prevUrl = "none", paging;
    ImageView image;
    Bitmap myBitmap;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Bundle gotBasket = getIntent().getExtras();
        // gotToken = gotBasket.getString("Access_Token");
        static_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/awaaziitkgp/feed?access_token="
                + static_token;


        setContentView(R.layout.news_feed);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final TextView button1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final TextView newPosts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nextPosts);
        final TextView prevPosts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.previousPosts);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();
        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
        }


private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
    }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                    JSONObject pagingObj = jsonObj.getJSONObject("paging");
                    // String nextObj = pagingObj.getString("next");
                    nextUrl = pagingObj.getString("next");
                    // JSONObject prevObj= pagingObj.getJSONObject("previous");
                    prevUrl = pagingObj.getString("previous");
                    Log.d("contact.length", String.valueOf(contacts.length()));

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        String message = null;
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        data.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        if (c.has("description") == true) {
                            message = c.getString("description");
                            Log.d("Getting Description", message);
                        }
                        if (c.has("picture") == true) {
                            try {
                                Log.d("IT HAS PICTURE! TADA!!", "Image Found");

                                imgUrl = c.getString("picture");
                                Thread thread = new Thread(){
                                    public void run(){
                                      System.out.println("Thread Running");
                                      NewsFeed.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                            @Override 
                                            public void run() { 
                                               //Your code to run in GUI thread here 

                                                URL newUrl = null;
                                                try {
                                                    newUrl = new URL(imgUrl);
                                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                                myBitmap = getBitmapFromUrl(newUrl);
                                                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                  };

                                  thread.start();



                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("ERROR LOADING IMAGE",
                                        "Why you do this, InputStream? Why?");
                            }
                        }else{
                            NewsFeed.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                @Override 
                                public void run() { 
                                   //Your code to run in GUI thread here 
                            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                                        }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }
```

Comment: "I am getting a nullpointerexception at `image.setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);`" -- then presumably `image` is `null`.

Comment: i have initialized it as 'image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);' before

Comment: I have specified it in onCreate() method and setImageResource() is in an AsyncTask class

Comment: @hXT1022 : Have made any recent changes to layout files? The `R.java` file may be out-of-sync - try cleaning the project and rebuilding.

Comment: is the AsyncTask launched before or after the onCreate method?

Comment: After the onCreate()

Comment: @Squonk: That didn't help. Thanks though.

Comment: And you're using a fragment or an activity? maybe it's better if you provide us more code, so we can try to see where is the problem

Comment: My main activity NewsFeed.java is  ListActivity and GetContacts.java is AsyncTask

Comment: @Guillermo Merino : I have added extra code in the question

Comment: @hXT1022 : Why are you creating a `Thread` inside `doInBackground(...)` of the `AsyncTask`? The `doInBackground(...)` method runs in its own `Thread`.. If you want to update UI components with an `AsyncTask` then either wait until `doInBackground(...)` is complete and return the results to `onPostExecute(...)` (which runs on the UI thread). If you want periodic UI updates during te `doInBackground(...)` execution then call `updateProgress(...)` which in turn, calls the `onProgressUpdate(...)` method (which also runs on the UI thread).

Comment: Thread is to ensure that application continues without waiting for image to get downloaded. I want to update image in that specific list item not all the list items. That's why I cannot do it in post execute.

Comment: Image should update in that for loop only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to inflate a layout then use a view from another layout..

since you used R.layout.activity_main you can only use the views inside that layout nothing more..

but in your case you used the image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dice1); which will reference a null value because it reside in your MAIN.xml not in activity_main.

So what you need to do is instead of using the activity_main layout use the appropriate layout which is setContentView(R.layout.MAIN);

Comment: There can be another reasons for his problem, not necessarily the one you're describing. Maybe he is executing the AsyncTask before the onCreate method, maybe this view is inside a fragment...

Comment: I am using activity_main as a 'ListView' and 'imageView1' is in a 'list_item.xml' layout

Answer (score 4):

Here you can get a solution.

```
 ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_view1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.cover);
```

XML Snippet:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: it gives NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION at the same line

Comment: When you add "cover.png" image in res/drawable/ after that use this code.